# How Can A Timestamp Be Redone Without Invalidating the Signature?

Tags: timestamp

RFC 3161 - 4.3 states that:

> Thus, any token signed by the TSA SHOULD be time-stamped again (if authentic copies of old CRLs are available) or notarized (if they aren't) at a later date to renew the trust that exists in the TSA's signature.

How is this re-time-stamping done without invalidating the signature? Is this the responsibility of the client that's using the TSA service or is it the services? Does this validation include backdating (so that the original date is kept accurate)?

I can't really wrap my head around this process.

Comment: I think "Time-stamped" means resigned, with a new key.

Comment: @MargaretBloom But does it not defeat the purpose of a TSA? Isn't the idea of using a TSA that it would stay valid forever if it was valid at the time of signing? How does this even apply to document signing then? The person that legally signed the document might not even be around anymore, but the document might still be needed by other parties such as inheritors or previous employers etc.

Comment: As I understand it, point 4.3 is all about the finite lifetime of keys. A TSA should use a key length big enough to ensure a long key lifetime but no key has an infinite lifetime. So 4.3. is a warning about assuming a TS document will last forever. Inheritors should use the document before it expires, and employers should renew it before it expires. This is no different from a land ownership document with a seal from an authority pre-USA (say), it was surely binding then but, unless was renewed under the new government, it is useless now.